# Restoring a 1930s Hardwood Floor with Dampness Issues Near Hearth

Tags: wood, flooring, hardwood-floor, uk, damp

We’re restoring the original hardwood floor in our 1930s semi-detached house and have encountered a dampness issue. The problem area is around the slate hearth, where the wood’s edge is damp. We suspect the dampness is due to contact with a wet substrate beneath the hearth, possibly caused by rising damp.

[image]

<sup>Note: the green on the wood is not mould but remnant carpet glue</sup>

Notably, there’s a 60-90 cm space under the floorboards, and their undersides seem dry. We’ve uncovered previously buried airbricks at the rear of the house to improve airflow under the floor. This leads us to believe that the dampness is isolated to the area where the floorboards contact the hearth’s substrate.

We’re keen to restore the floorboards but are concerned about the damp area. I have partially excavated the substrate, which seems to have helped. Would inserting a waterproof membrane between the substrate and the wood be effective? Alternatively, should we consider more extensive damp proofing measures, such as removing the hearth and log burner? (Though preferring a cost effective solution).

Any insights or advice on dealing with this dampness issue while preserving the original floor would be greatly appreciated.

Just a bit of additional context, we live in the UK so have cold and wet winters.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the stove have a water jacket?  Does it warm water pipes too?  It could also be water coming down the flue.

Comment: No, just a wood burner. No plumbing anywhere near the area

Comment: Any chance of leaks in the chimney to which the stovepipe is attached, or in flashing around the chimney? Water leaks can travel a fair distance, and proximity to the fireplace would lead me to get that inspected.

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik - struggling to find any evidence of this. No water marks or damage evident. What would be signs of this?

Comment: @tedioustortoise, no, I have no suggestion, other than routine chimney inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, isolating the floor ends from the hearth base.

It would be a dusty mess, but with care, a dust barrier can be assembled with wood framing to make a wall structure with plastic walls to contain the dust. A vacuum would be of great value too.

With the proper protection in place a masonry saw blade can be bought for a circular saw, or one can be rented with the proper blade on it. This arangement can cut up to 2 1/4" in depth total. You may not need tat much or the heath base may be i the way to allow the full depth to happen. Using the saw cut the cement away from the ends of the wood flooring, creating the airspace you need to keep the moisture from wicking into the wood. There are other types of masonry saws available that can do the job if the cement is in the way.

I tried to post a picture of a masonry saw that is usually available for rent, but it failed to upload a number of times.